# Php header: about double links

Tags: php

I have a link to pageA. I want the user to go to pageB passing by pageA in a unique link. How is it possible? To go to pageA by clicking a link I do the following:

```
<?php header('Location: http://www.pageA.com/'); ?>
```

Comment: Your code is correct. what you want to do exactly ? On pagea, you might want to check $_GET variables before `header()` call.

Comment: I need to go to PageB passing from PageA =)

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to write `<?php header('Location: http://www.pageB.com/'); ?>` inside page A

Comment: Hi! I have not control on that page... My case is that: I have an affiliation link for 30 products. But I want to send my users also to other products without affiliation link. But I need to have although the "Click" given by affiliation links! So I would like to make people passing from a page but opening another...